# Checking if a string contains words in a specific order

Tags: c#, string, foreach, conditional-statements

Here's an interesting question, Say you have a list which contains 3 sentences such as:

> Bill cat had
>
> Bill had a cat
>
> Cat had Bill

How would I use the .Contains() or any other method to check if the sentences in the List contains words in a specific order, algorithm shown below:

> **1) Run Sentence List through foreach loop**
>
> **2) Check if sentence contains words in this order => Bill + had + cat**
>
> **3) return that sentence**

So every other sentence is returned false since the order of words is different. Any ideas on implementing this, folks? :)

Comment: you can have regex to find the matching string from list

Comment: Can the 'order of words' condition be satisfied? @jadavparesh06

Comment: Yup that condition can be specified by regex

Comment: In Above loop we need return true for only Bill had a Hat??? For other statements we need return false.? Is that ur question?

Comment: Yes sir it is! @sarathkumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below solution It works.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("Bill cat had");
            list.Add("Bill had a cat");
            list.Add("Bill had cat");
            list.Add("Cat had Bill");
            Regex rex = new Regex(@"((Bill)).*((had)).*((cat))");

            foreach (string str in list)
            {
                if (rex.IsMatch(str))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works on my console application properly, Don't know why it threw exception for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> ss = new List<string>();
ss.Add("Bill had cat");
string inputstring = "In 2012, Bill had a cat";
foreach (string s in ss)
{
    string[] split = s.Split(' ');
    string regex = ".*";
    for(int a = 0; a<split.Length;a++)
        regex += split[a]+".*";
    Match temp = Regex.Match(inputstring, regex);
    if (temp.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("String \"" + inputstring  + "\" matches");
    }
}
```

try if this works, this is case sensitive so take that into account

Comment: Hmmm it actually returns true for the "Bill cat had". How do I change it, I kind of don't understand the logic behind that code sir

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: Since I need it to return true for the conditioned mentioned in the question, my input string is "In 2012, Bill had a cat". But it returns false.

Comment: But "Bill cat had" would be false for that string or? I mean cat comes after had. the string "Bill had a cat" is correct since it is in that order.

Comment: Yes it would be false, I want it to be true if and only if it has the words "Bill + had + Cat" one after the other. Something like: Bill > had > Cat. Sorry for the repeated nagging :)

Comment: Changed my answear, try it now. If you want a difrent match just change the **"Bill cat had"** in **ss.Add("Bill cat had");** to another string that would then follow that order

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> sentences = new List<string>();
    static List<string> pattern = new List<string>();
    static List<string> results = new List<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //sentences are in order
        sentences.Add("Bill cat had");
        sentences.Add("Bill had a cat");
        sentences.Add("Cat had Bill");
        sentences.Add("Bill had cats");

        //patters are in order
        pattern.Add("Bill");
        pattern.Add("had");
        pattern.Add("cat");

        // call the searchString method
        results = searchString(sentences, pattern);

        foreach (string res in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }

        Console.Read(); // just keep program running when debugged
    }

    static List<string> searchString(List<string> sentences, List<string> patterns)
    {
        bool result = false;
        List<string> resultLIst = new List<string>();

        foreach (string sen in sentences)
        {
            int j = 0;
            foreach (string pat in pattern)
            {
                if (sen.Contains(pat))
                {
                    if (j <= sen.IndexOf(pat))
                    {
                        result = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    j = sen.IndexOf(pat);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (result)
                resultLIst.Add(sen); // get the matching sentence
        }

        return resultLIst; // return matchin sentences
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer also

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = "";
            string[] list = new string[] { "Bill cat had", "Bill had a cat", "Cat had Bill" };
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                string[] splitString = item.Trim().Split(' ');
                int i = 0; bool IsValid = true;
                int count = 0;
                foreach (var sindividual in splitString)
                {
                    int j = CheckMatched(sindividual);
                    if (j != 0)
                    {
                        if (j > i)
                        {
                            i = j;
                            count++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            IsValid = false;
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (count >= 3 && IsValid)
                {
                    message += item + "   " + "yes it has t proper order \n";
                }
                else
                {
                    message += item + "   " + "Doesnt have proper order \n";
                }
            }

            lblMessage.Text = message;


        }


        int CheckMatched(string sStringtoCheck)
        {
            sStringtoCheck = sStringtoCheck.Trim().ToLower();

            if (sStringtoCheck.Contains("bill"))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (sStringtoCheck.Contains("had"))
            {
                return 2;
            }
            else if (sStringtoCheck.Contains("cat"))
            {
                return 3;
            }
            else return 0;
        }
```

this also works fine.. But little large